# preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '0'

Tags: php, preg-replace

The following piece of code always throws the error `preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '0'`. What could be the reason for that?

```
$logfile = preg_replace("/\+".preg_quote($dir)."(.*)\+".preg_quote("<>")."/", $log, $logfile);
```

$logfile is a string looking like this:

```
14/08/01:Sometext<>14/08/02:Sometext<>
```

etc

$dir has the format

```
14/08/01
```

Comment: `preg_quote()` needs to know your used regex delimiter to escape it as well.

Comment: Oh wow... So easy and didn't see it. Thank you!